# exporting and formatting data.frame as .dat table

Tags: r

I'm looking for help creating an input file (eg `df.dat`) from a `data.frame` for a legacy program that has very strict formatting requirements.  With this example `data.frame`:

```
location <- rep("GDWC1",6)
monyear <- rep(0215, 6)
day <- c(6,7,8,9,10,11)
value <- c(750.00, 3516.00, 8295.00, 11064.00, 3264.00, 111796.00)
df <- data.frame(location, monyear, day, value)
head(df)
# location monyear day  value
#1    GDWC1    0215   6    750
#2    GDWC1    0215   7   3516
#3    GDWC1    0215   8   8295
#4    GDWC1    0215   9  11064
#5    GDWC1    0215  10   3264
#6    GDWC1    0215  11 111796
```

My desired file export (eg say as a .dat, .txt) format is no header or row IDs, 6 spaces between the first and second column (which is always four values - here the 0215), right justified 3rd column (2-3 spaces between 2nd & 3rd column), and at least 2 spaces between 3rd and 4th column, and adding `.00` to the 4th column with decimal alignment enforced.

desired df.dat:

```
GDWC1      0215   6     750.00
GDWC1      0215   7    3516.00
GDWC1      0215   8    8295.00
GDWC1      0215   9   11064.00
GDWC1      0215  10    3264.00
GDWC1      0215  11  111796.00
```

I've been unsuccessful with `write.table()`, in getting the columns spacings, right justfication of the day column, and decimal alignment for the value column all correct. Any ideas? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an approach with `sprintf`:

```
result <- apply(df,1,function(x){
  paste0(x["location"],
         sprintf("%6s",""),
         sprintf("%04s",x["monyear"]),
         sprintf("%4s",x["day"]),
         sprintf("%11.2f",as.numeric(x["value"]))
         )})
write.table(result,
            file = "file.dat",
            col.names = FALSE,
            row.names = FALSE,
            quote = FALSE)

system("cat file.dat")
GDWC1      0215   6     750.00
GDWC1      0215   7    3516.00
GDWC1      0215   8    8295.00
GDWC1      0215   9   11064.00
GDWC1      0215  10    3264.00
GDWC1      0215  11  111796.00
```

See `help(sprintf)` for details on how the format works.

Comment: Brilliant! Cheers.